# SqlBulkCopy Alternative for Temporary Table on SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

Just want to ask if theres an alternative way like "SqlBulkCopy" on inserting data to Temporary Table on SQL Azure via Datatable or Dataset.

SqlBulkCopy seems not supported on SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2012:

> This is a known issue with SQL Azure and bulk copy. The only workaround is to upload to a non-temporary table. You can for example generate a temporary table name using a random guid to avoid collisions, then ensure you clean it up later. Another option is to upload data into a temp table using the TVP feature instead of SqlBulkCopy, let me know if you want some details on how to do this. They are working on fixing this but I don't have any ETA on when this fix will get done yet.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/51b26995-509f-419e-8545-3a3c16a6fc14/sqlbulkcopy-raises-exception-when-targeting-a-temporary-table?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkCopy to temp table is now supported in SQL DB V12. You don't need these hacks now. If you are still on V11, TVP is the way to go.